# HEVC (H.265) not natively supported in Android?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, hevc, h.265

I'm a little confused, I'm looking at the media recorder class and see the HEVC (or H.265) is not listed as an encode format in the Android APIs. See here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html

Apparently there are devices which support HEVC like the Galaxy S4. See here:
http://www.androidos.in/2013/03/samsung-galaxy-s-4-hevc-h-265-support/

Does this mean that Samsung put their own HEVC libraries into the media framework of Android? Is that the right way to view this?

Comment: "Does this mean that Samsung put their own HEVC libraries into the media framework of Android?" -- my guess is that they added HEVC support to their own recording app, not the framework.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Support for HEVC has been added in API 24(Nougat). The docs have already been updated with this.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with HEVC for a few years now and when we had developed the media player for a sample test, there was no library inclusion for that. We had typically ported our encoder. You are correct that Hevc libraries will be included into the Media Framework of Android.